# Select2 clear button does not work for the first copied selectbox

Tags: jquery-select2

What I want to make:

When you click "Click here!," the selectbox multiplies. All of them can be identical, but need a clear button for each. The code I wrote is at the bottom.

The problem:

The clear button does not work for **only the first box**. Why does it happen, and why doesn't it happen for the rest?

Here is the error I got on Firefox console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: self.dataAdapter is null
    _registerDomEvents https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.js:5703
    jQuery 7
    _handleClear https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.js:2001
    [traceback continues]
```

The error message changes a bit in different browsers, like `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'current')` in Edge. However, the problem is the same: the `dataAdapter` is null.

I did a research a bit and a similar bug has been reported. However, none of the solutions worked. Is this a select2 bug, or I am doing something wrong?

Here is the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/nagi_asafor/pe4yz8w0/